# GitHub.com — как стянуть Releases/Tags без потери истории коммитов?

Tags: git, контроль-версий, github

Доброе время суток! В общем, имею проблему, есть 2 версии проекта на [GitHub](https://github.com), первая версия приложения поддерживает 6 версию iOS, вторая только 7 iOS. На 6 версию уже, было дело, немного забили, и не поддерживали её, в ветке master - версию приложения уже только от 7-ки. Старая версия была залита на [GitHub](https://github.com) как **Releases/Tags**.

Собственно, вопрос: каким образом с [GitHub](https://github.com) можно стянуть **Releases/Tags** так, чтобы остались комиты?

Заливал таким образом (все действия для создания тэга выполнял на сайте):

[image]

Далее:

[image]

Comment: а как именно Вы залили в виде "Releases/Tags"?

Comment: @KoVadim, Дополнил ответ скрин шотами.

Comment: то есть, я правильно понимаю, что в мастере просто в свое время пометили коммит тегом, где была рабочая версия для 6 оси?

Comment: @KoVadim, Да, именно так и поступил. На данный момент в ветке master храниться версия, которая только для iOS7. А мне нужно слить данный тег, там версия, которая для 6 iOS.

Comment: можно на базе метки создать ветку. Где то так

    git checkout master
    git branch -b for_ios6 Releases

где for_ios6 - это название новой ветки, Releases - это имя тега. `-b` сразу и переключит в эту ветку. Дальше с этой веткой можно работать как обычно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался с помощью [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com).